# Top-Down Parsing Implement in c#

Tags: c#, parsing

I want to implement Top-Down Parsing by c# language is there any source to show me the way. I mean good method and description to implement or algorithms.
for example here are some steps to implement : 
1- developing a Grammar 
2- LL1 Parsing 
3- Construct the parser.  
These steps are in order and order is very important to give you correct answer.

Comment: uh what? What is the question?

Comment: Question is How I can implement these steps (top-down parsing steps) in c# language as well ? is there any article or code for that or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following MSDN Article ["Create a Language Compiler for the .NET Framework"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx) covers the very basics of the steps you defined. And targets .NET/C#

For more detail on each area you should probably not be concerend about finding C# specific texts.

Answer (score 0):

Top-down parsers are also called recursive descent parsers, you can [search for that](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=how+to+write+a+recursive+descent+parser).

I wouldn't concentrate on searching for C# - as long as the examples and tutorials you find are in procedural languages, you shouldn't have too much difficulty translating them to C#.

Additionally, maybe take a look at these pair of short, but useful, articles:

- [Introduction to grammars](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~zdu/parsdemo/gramintro.html)
- [Introduction to recursive-descent parsers](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~zdu/parsdemo/recintro.html)